# .htaccess redirection without keeping old sites, http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to ask for your help and opinions about my new website pages redirection.
I have an old website which has old design and too complicated etc. and now I made a new one, but the old has a very good position on google search so I would like to hold this position.
I use .htaccess for redirect my old pages to the new like this:

```
redirect 301 /oldwebsite/oldfile.html https://www.newsite.com/index.php
```

It is works but I have some question and problem:

1, The old website pages are .html pages the new is all .php

2, The old website is http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html but now I made, and I would like to redirect the pages to https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php

3, If it is possible I don't want to take the old pages a folder such as "oldwebsite" and make the redirections like this:

```
redirect 301 /oldwebsite/oldfile.html https://www.newsite.com/index.php
```

if it is possible, I would like to delete the old pages (fully) because it has to much space on the web hosting.

4, On the old website I had too many .html pages such as material1.html, material2.html ....material32.html, and I would like to redirect the files to only one new page.

Maybe something like this, but I think it is not correct:

```
redirect 301 /oldwebsite/materials/material1.html https://www.newsite.com/materials.php
redirect 301 /oldwebsite/materials/material2.html https://www.newsite.com/materials.php
redirect 301 /oldwebsite/materials/material3.html https://www.newsite.com/materials.php
```

.
.
.

```
redirect 301 /oldwebsite/materials/material3223.html https://www.newsite.com/materials.php
```

I don't have too much experience with the .htaccess but, as a layman I thought about it but it does not work:

```
redirect 301 http://www.mywebsite/contact.html https://www.mywebsite.com/contact.php
```

And then the http://www.mywebsite/contact.html page is deleted just I write a line in a .htaccess file because if somebody remembers my old page and types it on the browser it could be to redirect the new site, even if the old file has already been deleted from the storage.

This is how I would think but unfortunately, I have not been able to achieve it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at the Old Site main directory `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

So , now you will redirect any request to old site to `https` new site.

Go to New Site and put  the following code at the main directory `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.newsite.com/404.php
```

The old site will be redirected to new site and in term of SEO and Ranking , in your case , the Ranking will be not affected with `301` permanent redirection unless there are some pages in old site not at new site and there is no rule to handle error document in new site and that why i added this line `ErrorDocument 404 https://www.newsite.com/404.php`  and for `.html` extension i put this line to catch any `.html` and remove it , so if user request `http://www.oldsite.com/somepage.html` it will go to `https://www.newsite.com/somepage` and if there is `somepage.php` Ok otherwise it will be considered error and go to error page "404.php".

test the code and if every things work fine change this line in old site `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

with this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now the entire Old Site will be directed permanently to New Site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer!
At now I have my website such as: http://www.mywebsite.com
It has the old design, .html pages etc.

The new web site would still remain at this domain only delete old files, redirect it to newly created .php files and switch from http to https, but the site's name and availability would remain https://www.mywebsite.com.
So, I have only one htaccess file and I only have to redirect old html files to php files and if possible delete these old html files as well as if someone is looking for my site then redirect to a new php file.

If I understand in your answer this would be a solution if I want to redirect the .html pages of an old domain to the .php pages of a completely new domain name, which is referred to as http instead of https. For me, this domain would be left, but I would like to completely remove and change the old .html sites to new .php sites.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I've tried to solve it and the following solution works but I don't know if it's right.

This is currently the content of my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

redirect 301 /oldsite_1.html https://www.mywebsite.com/contact.php
redirect 301 /oldsite_2.html https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php
.
.
.
```

So at now on my storage contains the old .html files and the new .php files also.
It works if I'm looking for old websites to go to http://www.mywebsite.com/oldsite_1.html this will redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com/contact.php. This also works if I delete the oldsite_1.html file from storage (which would be the ultimate goal of not keeping old files on storage).

Is this a good solution?
Will not my site lose this old position during google search (even if I delete old files)?